# How to calculate a GeoJSON's bounds without adding it to the map

Tags: leaflet

I have a GeoJSON object, and I want to get its bounds without adding it to the map, similarly to what I can get with `L.polygon().getBounds()`.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Perhaps there is a straightforward conversion of the `L.geoJSON` object to `L.polygon`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you parse your GeoJSON object through [`L.geoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) factory so that it builds a Leaflet GeoJSON layer group (which extends a Feature Group), you can have Leaflet compute the bounds of its child layers (features) using the group's [`getBound()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds) method, without needing to add the group to a map.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var geojsondata = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [2.34, 48.86]}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [2.36, 48.86]}}]};

var geojsongroup = L.geoJSON(geojsondata);
//geojsongroup.addTo(map);

alert(geojsongroup.getBounds().toBBoxString());

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```